# Change Terminal Font in Coder

Tags: shell, debian, xtermjs, coder

I am using [Coder](https://coder.com/) to host a Debian installation, and I would like to change the terminal font to UbuntuMono from Nerd Fonts. I've downloaded and installed the font, as confirmed by running `fc-list`:

```
[...]
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold Oblique
/home/coder/.fonts/UbuntuMonoNerdFont-Regular.ttf: UbuntuMono Nerd Font:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuMathTeXGyre.ttf: DejaVu Math TeX Gyre:style=Regular
[...]
```

Now I understand that my next step should be to set my terminal emulator to use that font as the default. Running `echo $TERM` gives `Xterm`, so I created a `.Xresources` file with the following contents:

```
xterm*font:UbuntuMono Nerd Font:size=16
```

Next I try to run `xrdb -merge .Xresources`, but I get the following error:
`xrdb: Can't open display ''`. I tried setting my `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0` per a post I found, but that just results in the error being `xrdb: Can't open display ':0'`. I'm at a total loss here. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing and how I can change fonts?

Comment: `TERM=Xterm` just means they support xterm-compatible control sequences. It doesn't mean Coder _actually_ uses xterm, or X11 at all -- if I were building their stack I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: Understood. Stupid question then - how can I tell what terminal emulator I'm using? Launching terminal from coder just opens a terminal window, and I can't find anywhere in their docs what emulator it uses.

Comment: Good question. I'd need to know a lot more about the moving parts to answer that. Backing up -- what's your host operating system? If you're running an X11-based windowing system, we can use `xwininfo` to ask what the local parts are; if it's Windows or native MacOS/Cocoa, then we'd need different platform-specific tools.

Comment: The host OS is Debian. Running ```xwininfo``` yields a similar error to xrdb: ```xwininfo: error: unable to parse display name ""```

Comment: When I say "host OS", I mean the OS _you're_ running on your own computer where you display the Coder VM's output, not the OS run by Coder. In this context, the OS run by Coder is the "guest", not the host.

Comment: And it's the _host_ where you'd want to run `xwininfo` (or an equivalent platform-appropriate tool), not the guest, to see what the executable that's actually responsible for your local terminal window is. If we find out that local terminal window is something that displays remotely-presented graphics, that tells us the font configuration is on the remote side; whereas if it does local font rendering, then we know the font needs to be installed locally.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I understand. I'm running Windows 10. I'm accessing the Coder instance via a web interface though, as opposed to ssh from a terminal application on my PC or anything like that (if that's relevant)

Comment: Okay. Next step -- if you pull up your browser debugger and ask it what the DOM element where the terminal is displayed is, what is it?

Comment: (a lot of the possible options, like `canvas`, are things that _could_ be used to display graphics, or _could_ render text, depending on usage; but if it's, say, SVG or such, then we can actually look at the content to see if the text rendering is happening browser side or on the remote end; if it's browser-side, then you need Coder's web interface to explicitly support font installation, whereas if there are actual graphical frames being sent over the wire... well, at that point, I'd ping their customer support, since all the magic happens on their server side)

Comment: It's a ```<div class="xterm-screen">``` within a ```<div dir="ltr" class="terminal xterm">```

Comment: And inside those `div`s are what? If you keep expanding DOM elements, do you get text or images at the bottom?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256796/discussion-between-notgene-and-charles-duffy).